# remove start and end spacing of text inside table cell

Tags: css, html-table, spacing

This is my code ,

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td style="font-size:180px;text-align:center;
      display:inline-block;">O</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/rf80aq5k/)

I have a table cell and it has a character `O` inside .
As you can see , there are spaces between start and end of character ( between left border of cell and `O` , between right border of cell and `O` .
I just want to remove it . I want the character `O` to touch the left and right border of cell .
I have tried by adjusting cell width , using `display:block` for cell style .
But unfortunately , non of those work .

Comment: so,why are you using table border?do you really need that border?.just get read off the border.and see how it looks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space you are seeing is coming up with the font family, not from the html elements. If you want to achieve your desired result you can apply some negative margin and get the result like below.

```css
table {
border:1px solid #000;
}
.zero {
font-size:180px;
text-align:center;
display:inline-block;
margin-right:-7px;
margin-left:-7px;
}
```

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
  <td class="zero">O</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: exactly what I need !